# EWS retrieve ForwardingAddress of O365 Account

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm trying to retrieve the `ForwardingAddress` setting using the `EWS Java API`.
This one is not linked to the inbox rules (where you can setup forwarding as well). 
It can be manually set through the O365 Web-UI under `options` -> `account` -> `connected accounts` where you can set up a forwarding smtp address (and opt in for keeping a copy in the inbox by enabling a checkbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the forwarding Address is a specific Active Directory property that isn't made available in any of the EWS directory operations (I don't believe you can get it via the Graph API either). The only method you can use to get that are Remote Powershell cmdlets

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! So I think i need to use inbox rules only.